# Restricting contract deployment on a private eth fork

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, dapps, genesis

I have a private fork of the ETH blockchain and I'd like to modify the source to allow deploying contracts from a single address only using this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41170/is-it-possible-to-fork-ethereum-so-that-only-specified-accounts-can-deploy-new). The caveat, however, is that instead of a single wallet address I need this to be a dApp; or, in other words, I need to be able to whitelist any wallet address to deploy a contract (one-time). So here are my thoughts:

1. deploy contracts via a proxy contract (e.g. one hard-coded into the `genesis.json`) and create a front-end dApp (kinda like Remix) from which anyone could deploy an arbitrary contract (but from nowhere else) via the proxy
2. instead of limiting deployment to a single address, store the whitelist in a smart contract e.g. `mapping(address => boolean)` and have the node source code check that whitelist
3. deploy a basic ERC20 token and have the token holders enabled to deploy contracts (but no one else); so instead of whitelisting a wallet I can transfer the ERC20 token to whomever I'd like to enable to deploy contracts

Which one of these three (if any) is actually possible and secure?

For #1 I know that I would have to create the front-end and have it talk to the proxy, but it is even possible/realistic to deploy contracts this way? I mean, usually when delegating calls the sender is not the proxy but the actual wallet creating the transaction, so it is possible to even implement it this way?

I like #2 more than #1 but I have no idea how the Geth source code can "talk" to a deployed smart contract to achieve this. Is it even possible? Could you point me to an example written in Go which does that?

Actually, #3 would be perhaps the most elegant as it wouldn't require a smart contract to store any wallet addresses, just the Geth source would have to check the `balanceOf` the sender's wallet (but not for the native coin balance but rather the ERC20 token balance). Is this possible? Can such a token be deployed in the `genesis.json`?

I'd appreciate any pointers and/or warnings what else to pay attention to.

Thank you

Comment: For me #2 is quite the same as #3. Probably #1 is easier to implement if you know solidity and a little of go, #2 will be harder since you have to know how to access contract storage from the geth code.

Comment: yeah, but would that even work? I mean, in #1, if I use an usual proxy, the sender address will be the wallet which tries to deploy the contract, not the proxy, right?!

Comment: I mean the proxy contract could be anything, it could be a precompiled contract. that accepts as paremeters the bytecode, the creator, etc. You could make it more complicated, using a DAO for example, so it will be closer to #3.